# Django: Update one data from Database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two html files for attendance_in and out, just a simple forms. If I want to punch in, the data was created (begin_time). I'm having a hard time updating the end_time.  This is my code.

models.py

```py
class Attendance(models.Model):
    begin_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name="in")
    end_time = models.TimeField(verbose_name="out")
```

views.py

```py
def attendance_in(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'attendance_in.html')
    if request.method =='POST':
        begin_time = request.POST.get('begin_time')
        Attendance.objects.create(begin_time=begin_time,)
        return redirect('/user/attendance/out')

def attendance_out(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'attendance_out.html')
    if request.method =='POST':
      .......
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('attendance/in/', views.attendance_in),
    path('attendance/out/', views.attendance_out),
]
```

The attendance_in was working. But I am not sure how to update the end_time.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do like this:

```
   record = Record.objects.get(id=1)
   record.name = "new record name"
   record.save(update_fields=['name'])
```

This is the way you can update single field.

Update field must be inside save() method